# XaringanExtra misplaces scribbles when printing from Chrome as PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

Take the demo presentation at:

https://pkg.garrickadenbuie.com/xaringanExtra/scribble/#1

and draw some scribbles like the following:

[image: scribble1]

After you print that from Chrome, you get the following PDF:

[image: scribble2]

Is there some workaround? Thanks!

(There is [issue](https://github.com/gadenbuie/xaringanExtra/issues/149) open, but with no answer.)

Comment: Cool. We need XaringanExtra for it?

Comment: Thanks, @manro! I guess so, that we need XaringanExtra to add handwritten comments (with a drawing tablet) to the slides and save those comments to deliver, as a PDF, the slides+comments to students afterwards.

Comment: @PaulSmith I try to figure out today later, where is a problem. Are you a teacher? :)

Comment: Thanks, @manro! I am a lecturer at a university.

Comment: @PaulSmith Nice, can I ask you like an expert? Can I enter in any university for free and study remotely?

Comment: @manro, to get a university degree and studying remotely, it is nowadays perfectly possible, but unfortunately not by free (if you want a diploma). However, you can study remotely a wide variety of university courses. See: [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) and [edX](https://www.edx.org/).

Comment: @PaulSmith Bad( I want a diploma. But! Can I receive a grant for online-studying in any Uni? ```So, return to our task. I tried to save as PDF this presentation and self-made one. All is nice. I haven't Chrome, but have Opera(same engines with it).```

Comment: @PaulSmith But, yes! When we make ```Print``` - this bug is here. In ```Mozilla + Print``` is ok.

Comment: I doubt that a university degree diploma can be earned without paying fees, @manro. However, some universities help financially some students, when they lack financial resources or when they are top students. You may want to check that out with your local universities. `Firefox+Print to PDF` seems to work fine with the demo presentation, but not with other presentations.

Comment: @PaulSmith I think we can't solve it. Need an intervention of the package developers. As seems, ```"...invisible margins move our slides..."```

Comment: Thanks anyway, @manro! I guess your conclusion is right.

Comment: @PaulSmith I'm almost confident. Test presentation after printing to PDF has 16 pages instead of 10...(Mozilla)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. But it requires a little manual work.

**So, step-by-step.**

1. Open our Xaringan presentation in the Opera... Why not Mozilla - I don't know how to do `step 3` there :)
2. Draw what we want at the pages.
3. Save our presentation page-by-page via "Page -> Save as PDF..."
4. When all pages are saved in our working directory, we can combine them in the one file with `pdftk` (install, if you haven't). As we are R-users now, do it by this way:

   ```
   system("pdftk Page1.pdf Page2.pdf Page3.pdf cat output XarPres.pdf")
   ```

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @manro! Unfortunately, it does not work here -- the misplacement of the scribbles persists, if one tries with a different presentation (not with the demo one).

Comment: @PaulSmith Sorry then, I haven't any ideas yet. Try last Opera, I did in it...

Comment: I will try on Opera, @manro! Thanks!